# How to check if DNS is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, dns, dnscrypt-proxy

I have installed [DNSCrypt](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-linux-with.html) , its [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/technology/dnscrypt/) encrypted DNS patch for Ubuntu & other Linux users & it's working fine.

How do I know if my DNS is encrypted?
I have googled but didn't find anything.

**Status**

```
one@onezero:~$ status dnscrypt 
dnscrypt start/running, process 1013
one@onezero:~$ sudo netstat -atnlp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1013/dnscrypt-proxy
```

#### Updated

Wireshark

#### @Alvar

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## without DNSCrypt

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check it with `Wireshark` by listening to your network card, just follow these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install wireshark` (paste it into a terminal)
2. start it from a terminal with `sudo wireshark` (you need to be **sudo** to be able to listen to your network card.)
3. then **start listening** and filter out everything but your own ip.

Now just check if the **dns** protocols are encrypted.

1. use the filter to only show `dns`
2. Stop the scan.
3. click on a list item that says **dns** and comes from your ip.
4. Now click on the transmission protocol to see if it's encrypted.

Comment: @OneZero click on the red highlighted area that says **dns**, look in there, you should find out if it's encrypted in there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OpenDNS as the dnscrypt supporting DNS server, a way to check if it's working is to use one of these commands:

`drill txt debug.opendns.com`

`dig txt debug.opendns.com`

The answer text should contain a line where it says "dnscrypt enabled":

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "server 11"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "flags 22 2 222 2"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "id 6666666"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "source 209.6.69.160:44444"
debug.opendns.com.  0   IN  TXT "dnscrypt enabled (...)"
```

Comment: `drill` requires package `ldnsutils`, although `dig` works, and `nslookup -type=txt debug.opendns.com` also works.

Answer (score 1):

I installed dnscrypt 1.1 on Ubuntu 12.10.

I edited `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to comment out

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

Then add `/etc/init/dnscrypt.conf` and include in it the following:

```
 description "dnscrypt startup script"

 start on (local-filesystems and started dbus and stopped udevtrigger)
 stop on runlevel [016]

 script
         exec /usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy -a 127.0.0.1 -d
 end script
```

Next I changed my network settings to to use 127.0.0.1 for DNS:

Then I rebooted and made sure `dnscrypt` was running and that `dnsmasq` was not:

```
 ps aux | grep dns
 root      6581  0.0  0.0  16116   720 ?        Ss   04:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy -a 127.0.0.1 -d
```

Then I opened `wireshark` to verify that DNS was encrypted:

It appears it isn't.

Visiting http://www.opendns.com/welcome/ verifies I am using opendns.

[image: ]]

Answer (score 0):

You go to [OpenDNS Welcome page](http://www.opendns.com/welcome/) and you should see something like "Welcome to OpenDNS! Your Internet is safer, faster, and smarter because you're using OpenDNS." This means you're using OpenDNS as your DNS provider and **if you haven't configured OpenDNS without dnscrypt** your DNS requests **should** be encrypted.

Another way would be to snoop the DNS traffic using wireshark, tcpdump, etc and see if it's indeed encrypted but that's more convoluted and requires some in-depth knowledge.

Comment: http://www.opendns.com/welcome/ > ya i been there before its about open-dns dns , let me verified on my laptop the one without encryption

Comment: same as it shows here

Comment: OpenDNS is not the only DNScrypt enabled provider. `sudo dnscrypt-proxy --daemon -a 127.0.0.2 --resolver-address=23.226.227.93:443 --provider-name=2.dnscrypt-cert.okturtles.com --provider-key=1D85:3953:E34F:AFD0:05F9:4C6F:D1CC:E635:D411:9904:0D48:D19A:5D35:0B6A:7C81:73CB` is one of many that do not use OpenDNS.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got it!

Run dnscrypt-proxy --deamonize (it should already be running)

1. Go to the Network icon at the top and go down to Network Settings.
2. Go to your current connection and click Configure...
3. Go to IPv4 Settings tab.
4. Under DNS Servers and Search Domains fields enter: 127.0.0.1
5. Head to http://opendns.com/welcome

If you get redirected to http://opendns.com/welcome/oops then it's not setup properly.

Sorry about that. I didn't want to go to the pain to set it all up, but it was remarkably easy! Well, hope you learned something. I sure did!

Comment: can i check quries are been sent yo which encrypted dns server ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, it's only going to be sent to a maximum of two possibilities in most home networking circumstances. Most likely you set those in your router or your /etc/resolv.conf file. So every time your computer asks for something, your router will ask those two DNS servers. No others because it doesn't know any others. If you really want to know you could put a machine with two NICs and Wireshark between your computer and router. Then you can read the packets that go across the computer. But, of course you have to know what you're looking for.

Comment: ty , good one , you should include this detail in your answer

Comment: Poke! Did you see my updated answer?

Comment: yes i did , its 127.0.0.2 if u r using upstart script as i m , see w8 help , already checked open dns welcome same on encrypted & on un-encrypted

Comment: They shouldn't be the same on boot encrypted and unencrypted. Unencrypted shouldn't work. Until you change you network settings back to use your router as the DNS. And then it would only be OpenDNS if you've set the OpenDNS servers in your router as well.

Comment: This answer doesn't prove encryption; it only proves that OpenDNS is in use, potentially in an unencrypted state via dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

dnscrypt-proxy  accepts  DNS  requests,  encrypts  and signs them using  * **dnscrypt** *  and forwards them to a remote dnscrypt-enabled resolver

Replies from the resolver are expected also to be encrypted and signed.

The proxy verifies the signature of replies, decrypts them, and  trans‐parently forwards them to the local stub resolver.

dnscrypt-proxy listens to 127.0.0.1 / port 53 by default.