# DNSCrypt-proxy works, but with incorrect permissions

Tags: 13.10, permissions, proxy

I have successfully installed and find myself in the middle of configuring dnscrypt-proxy for use on ubuntu 13.10 x64.  However I am running into some issues with permissions in general.

I have added a user with the following commmand:

`sudo adduser --system --quiet --home /run/dnscrypt --shell /bin/false --group --disabled-password --disabled-login dnscrypt`

and issued `dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize --user=dnscrypt` but without success.  So i tried just `--daemonize` and finally just `dnscrypt-proxy` which resulted in a UDP bind permission error.  Ran it as **root** and the error goes away.  `dnscrypt-proxy --user=dnscrypt` results in the error returning.  I'm guessing its failing because of some permission, but don't have a clue where to start or what to change at this point.

also i would like to run this at network startup or after login.  which i think i can manage, but if you have a suggestion it would just save me time.  I don't understand why I can't run this as `--user=dnscrypt` but root works fine.

edit:  Just to clarify a little more, I'm actually running elementary OS luna 0.2, which is based on ubuntu 13.10 (I believe)

Answer (score 1):

There is a PPA mantained by Sergei Schnatsel that should render things easier... OS luna is based on ubuntu 12.04.

More here: [link to PPA](https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/dnscrypt)

Answer (score 1):

Before you start, go to "edit connections" in the panel dropdown menu. Click on your current connection and select "Edit" and then select the ipv4 tab. For "method" select automatic DHCP addresses only. Then, type 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.2 respectively next to "Aditional DNS servers. Select ipv6 tab and for "Method" select "ignore" then click save and execute the following command.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Normally, dnscrypt-proxy must be used with sudo. The reason you do not see the UDP bind error using the `--daemonize` option is not because there is no error, it is because the `--daemonize` option (non-verbose) will show no output and thus does not show the error. I will fully explain here.

**First**, you have to **kill dnsmasq** to free up 127.0.0.1 or you will encounter the UDP bind permission error you spoke of.

**`sudo killall dnsmasq`**

Now, start dnscrypt-proxy on 127.0.0.1 with the following

**`sudo dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize --resolver-name=opendns`**

The following command does the same thing (with alot less typing).

**`sudo dnscrypt-proxy -d -R opendns`**

**Alternatively**, you may use 127.0.0.2 instead of 127.0.0.1 **without killing dnsmasq** to avoid the UDP bind error you spoke of.

**`sudo dnscrypt-proxy -d -R opendns -a 127.0.0.2`**

**For verbose mode**, run the following in an open terminal. Closing the terminal kills the running instance.

First, kill all instances of dnscrypt-proxy so you do not encounter a UDP bind error.

```
sudo killall dnscrypt-proxy
```

then you may run

**`sudo dnscrypt-proxy -R opendns`**

or

**`sudo dnscrypt-proxy -R opendns -a 127.0.0.2`**

**Finally,** to verify encryption is used, (opendns only) . . .

**`drill txt debug.opendns.com`**

or

**`dig txt debug.opendns.com`**

. . . "dnscrypt enabled" should show somewhere in the output

For a list of dnscrypt-proxy enabled resolvers, visit this page: https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv

Sources: http://dnscrypt.org/

https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy

[How to check if DNS is encrypted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105366/how-to-check-if-dns-is-encrypted/106573#106573)